# Finding a minimization problem corresponding to a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, optimization, finite-element-method

I was trying to find an equivalent minimization problem to the following PDE in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

$$
\Delta^2 u-\nabla \cdot (k(x,y) \nabla u)+\lambda u = f(x,y)
$$
where $\lambda >0 $ and $k(x,y) >0$.

With the following boundary conditions:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} =0 \text{ and } \frac{\partial }{\partial n} (\Delta u) - k(x,y) \frac{\partial u}{\partial n} =u\text{ on }\partial \Omega$$

I was also wondering whether the number of BC's are enough for a unique solution, as we have a fourth order PDE.

Thanks in advance for your helpful hints.

Answer (score 1):

If there exists a solution it will make the following $0$: $$u_o=\min_{u}\left\{\|\Delta^2u-\nabla \cdot (k(x,y)\nabla u) + \lambda u - f(x,y)\|_2^2 +\\+ \left\|\frac{\partial u}{\partial n}\right\|_2^2 +\left\|\frac{\partial}{\partial n}(\Delta u) - k(x,y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial n} - u\right\|_2^2\right\}$$

Comment: Wow, an answer after more than 3 years! Thanks for the effort, but after my graduation I began employment in a different field, so this answer doesn't make too much sense. Thanks anyway for the effort!

Comment: @ClausW yep I suspected so, but the site can be used as a library to search retroactively also. Who knows, maybe it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there exist a minimization problem for the given PDE. Then it can be found by computing:
$$J(u) = \int_\Omega uLu-uf~d\Omega$$
where $L$ is the operator of the PDE.
$$Lu = \Delta^2u-\nabla\cdot(k\nabla u) + \lambda u$$
You can use your boundary conditions and partial integration + Gauß to formulate the problem in the classical way with the norms and so on. If you need more steps let me know.